# Convert a string of ones and zeros to hex

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a simple way to convert a string of 1's and 0's to its hex equivalent.

```
[string]$bintest = "1100110101011111"
[long]$testnumber = [System.Convert]::ToInt32($bintest,2)
"{0:x4}" -f $testnumber
```

The code above works as needed but it seems like too many steps.
Is there a way to avoid converting the string to decimal before convering it to hex?

Comment: Your solution looks succinct. Why do you think there should be fewer steps? Are you looking for a more concise solution for convenience, or are you looking for a faster solution?

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd line could be condensed to `'{0:x4}' -f [Convert]::ToInt32($bintest,2)`, but that would eliminate just the step of storing the converted number in a variable, not the conversion itself. And no, that conversion cannot be avoided. There is no way of converting a binary number string directly to a hex number string. Well, technically you *could* write a custom parser that directly maps binary string patterns to their hex equivalent, but what would be the advantage of doing that? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve by avoiding the conversion?

Comment: mklement0; I'm somewhat of a Powershell novice so I just assume that if i can't reduce steps then I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Ansgar. No real problem I just like to avoid extra steps and unnecessary variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the shortest answer I could create

```
'{0:x}' -f [Convert]::ToInt32('1100110101011111',2)
```

Hope it helps

Edit: As I refreshed I saw the comment of @Ansgar Wiechers, two persons one idea I guess.